# Avoid "Unrecognized character" when compiling pyx to c without deleting the nordic (unrecognized) letters: æøå

Tags: python, cython

```
_______Main.pyx___________________________________________
*My script which uses nordic letters, these: "æ, ø, å"*
__________________________________________________________


_______setup.py___________________________________________
from distutils.core import setup 
from Cython.Build import cythonize 
setup(ext_modules = cythonize('Main.pyx')) 
__________________________________________________________
```

I am trying to convert my python code (.pyx) into c, the command I am using is:

`"python setup.py build_ext --inplace"`

But I am getting an "`unrecognized character`" error -->"class Nøgletal_Analyse:" 
(Which is not a surprise at all, afterall I am using nordic letters in my script)

How can the `unrecognized character error` be avoided, without deleting the nordic letters from the code?

Comment: Last time this was asked (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41671035/unicode-identifiers-in-cython) I suggested [reporting it as a bug](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues) - I still think this is the thing to do

Comment: But any suggestions on how to compile pyx code into c? (with "unrecognized characters" in it)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think you can.

Comment: @DavidW Just a thought (I am not very familiar with cython), would it be possible for every nordic letter: "æ,ø,å" , to replace each of those with a unique pattern such as: "J2faj37a8R". Compile the code, and then search for this pattern in the compiled c code, and replace them with their respective nordic letter?

Comment: Yes - any solution to this would be something like that, but it would probably need fairly complex changes to Cython. You also have to deal with the problem "what happens if you name a variable `J2faj37a8R`?" So it isn't an easy problem.

Comment: I have just now filed this as a bug: https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/2601.